# Having trouble compiling CV template

Tags: cv

I am using texmaker on ubuntu, and I was trying to create a cv. I downloaded this template from sharelatex. I tried compiling  with, LaTeX, XeLaTex, and PDFLaTeX and all of them had the same error "Undefined control sequence." I linked the source below, is it a question of the compiler being used or is it something in the latex code?

These are the errors that keep being repeated.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\cftdotfill #1->\def \@tempa 
                         {#1}\def \@tempb {\cftnodots }\ifx \@tempa \@te...
l.69 ... MSc, PhD, or something else}{2009 - 2013}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\cftdotfill #1->\def \@tempa {#1}\def \@tempb 
                                          {\cftnodots }\ifx \@tempa \@te...
l.69 ... MSc, PhD, or something else}{2009 - 2013}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
            \inaccessible 
l.69 ... MSc, PhD, or something else}{2009 - 2013}

Please don't say `\def cs{...}', say `\def\cs{...}'.
I've inserted an inaccessible control sequence so that your
definition will be completed without mixing me up too badly.
You can recover graciously from this error, if you're
careful; see exercise 27.2 in The TeXbook.

! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
            \inaccessible 
l.69 ... MSc, PhD, or something else}{2009 - 2013}

Please don't say `\def cs{...}', say `\def\cs{...}'.
I've inserted an inaccessible control sequence so that your
definition will be completed without mixing me up too badly.
You can recover graciously from this error, if you're
careful; see exercise 27.2 in The TeXbook.

! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
            \inaccessible 
l.69 ... MSc, PhD, or something else}{2009 - 2013}
```

https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/clean-cv

Comment: please always post the fill error message form the log in a `{}` code section. the full error message would say which command was undefined

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Added the error messages.

Comment: Change line 55 to look like `\begin{tabular*}{6.5in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}`.

Comment: Word of advice, that template is bad. I wouldn't trust it.

Comment: @Johannes_B it might be bad, but after looking at a bunch of CV templates. This one looked the best to me

Comment: You have still only provided very minimal information but it looks like a table of contents or other auxiliary file is corrupt so delete any .toc .aux or other temporary files and make sure to use `\protect` before any fragile command in a moving argument.

Comment: Did my comment above help?

Comment: @Johannes_B Still had all the same errors, but weirdly it still generated the pdf...

Comment: It should works with @Johannes_B comment unless you had changed the file linked

Answer (score 4):

You have a fragile command in an array preamble, the simplest way to fix that is to add

```
\usepackage{array}
```

compare

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    w
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    w
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```